# Lambda function package still large despite using a layer for dependencies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a Python Lambda and since I started using AWS X-Ray the package size has ballooned from 445KB to 9.5MB.

[image]

To address this and speed up deployments of my code, I have packaged my requirements separately and added a layer to my template. The [documentation](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/main/sample-apps/blank-python#setup) suggests that this approach should work.

> Packaging dependencies in a layer reduces the size of the deployment package that you upload when you modify your code.

```sh
pip install --target ../package/python -r requirements.txt
```

```yaml
Resources:
  ...

  ProxyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      CodeUri: proxy/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Layers:
        - !Ref ProxyFunctionLibraries
      Role: !GetAtt ProxyFunctionRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.8
      Tracing: Active

  ProxyFunctionLibraries:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: proxy-function-lib
      Description: Dependencies for the ProxyFunction.
      ContentUri: package/.
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.8
```

However, this doesn't seem to have prevented the Lambda from still packaging everything in the top layer, and every time I deploy the package is still 9.5MB. The new layer for some reason is 11MB in size, but that is only being deployed when a change is made.

How can I reduce the size of the Lambda function package?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the solution here was quite simple, although not obvious to non-Lambda experts.

As described in the question, the first step was to build the package library.

```
pip install --target ../package/python -r requirements.txt
```

However, when building the Lambda using `sam build -u` the same 'requirements.txt' file is used and the required dependencies were again being installed, this time as part of the app.

So all I had to do was remove the requirements that I wish packaged in a separate layer and rebuild. It does mean that I have to maintain 2x 'requirements.txt' but that is entirely manageable.

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/issues/350) and hopefully AWS will update their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same problem and solved it differently. Leaving this answer as a note to future question-seekers.

My current lambda structure is the following:

```
├── events
│   └── event.json
├── ingress
│   ├── app.py # lambda code
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
├── lib_layer # contains self written helpers and python dependencies
│   ├── helper.py
│   └── requirements.txt
├── samconfig.toml
├── template.yaml
└── tests
    ├── ...
```

In my `template.yaml` I have the following code snippets:

```yaml
SQSIngestion:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ingress/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Layers:
        - !Ref PythonLibLayer
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
```

```yaml
  PythonLibLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      ContentUri: lib_layer
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.9
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: python3.9
```

Since the Lambda Function already has the layer containing all dependencies + my helpers attached, the `requirements.txt` in `/ingress` can be omitted but works nevertheless when invoking the function in AWS. By calling
`sam build` will automatically build the dependency layer and ignore the function folder for building the dependencies.

As a tip, if working with VSCode, add in your `settings.json` the following line to fix pylances import error for self written packages.

```json
{
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["lib_layer"]
}
```